# Do Co-op vs AI bots scale?

Tags: league-of-legends

When playing Co-op vs AI do the bots scale in anyway depending on the level of the human summoner or will they just get easier to beat as your level goes up and gain more runes and masteries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Bots](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Bot) are available in two flavors: beginner and intermediate.  This is the only thing that affects the difficulty of the bots in game.

Bots do not scale vs summoner level, though [rewards](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Co-op_vs._AI) for beating them do.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on difficulty. Bots get boosted gold per second. Kills and cs don't mean much to them. As time goes on, they become more and more farmed as a state of their programming.

Answer (score 1):

I am 99% sure that the bots do not scale to your Summoner level, they just scale based on the difficulty you select. I am looking for word from Riot to confirm my beliefs now.